# how to pass data from express to my hbs view

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, handlebars.js

```
var Ticket = require('./models/ticket.js');

module.exports = function (app)
{

    app.get('/',function (req, res)
    {
        Ticket.find({},function (err, tickets)
        {
            if(err)
            {
                res.send(err)
            }
            else
            {

                console.log(tickets);
                res.render('index',tickets);
            }
        });

    });

    app.get('/upload',function (req, res)
    {
        res.render('upload');
    });

    app.post('/upload',function (req, res)
    {
        var ticket = new Ticket();

        ticket.type = req.body.type;
        ticket.price = req.body.price;
        ticket.time = req.body.time;
        ticket.date = req.body.date;

        ticket.save(function(err)
        {
            if (err)
            {
                res.send(err);
            }
            console.log('Created');
            res.redirect('/');
        });
    });
};
```

Above is my route.js file, where i have my routes for getting and posting my data. The console.log() in my get function is logging my data,but i'm having trouble passing that data to my hbs view. My hbs view is below.i'm simply trying to loop through the data.

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
{{#each tickets}}
        <div class="col m4 s12 l4">
            <div class="card blue-grey darken-1 z-depth-4">
                <div class="card-content white-text">
                    <span class="card-title">Date:{{date}}</span>
                    <ul>
                        <li>Time: {{time}}</li>
                        <li>Type:{{type}}</li>
                        <li>Price:&#8358; {{price}}</li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                <div class="card-action">
                   <div class="row valign-wrapper">
                       <div class="col m4 s4 l4">
                           <p class="valign">Quantity:</p>
                       </div>
                       <div class="col m8 s8 l8">
                           <select class="browser-default">
                               <option value="" disabled selected>0</option>
                               <option value="1">1</option>
                               <option value="2">2</option>
                               <option value="3">3</option>
                               <option value="3">4</option>
                               <option value="3">5</option>
                               <option value="3">6</option>
                           </select>
                       </div>
                   </div>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col m12">
                            <button class="btn bnt-link"><i class="fa fa-cart-plus" aria-hidden="true"></i></button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

{{/each}}

    </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
res.render('index',{tickets:tickets});
```